# Using texcount in Emacs to determine word count of Latex or tex file (wanting optional parameters)

Tags: emacs, latex, lisp, elisp, auctex

I have a function I use to determine the counts in latex and normally like it to use the command `brief`. How would I modify this to input options instead of running with `"-inc" "-brief"`. I could type in my own set of parameters in the minibuffer to run with the command texcount. Most likely it be best if the commands were separated by a comma then translated into the format below. Or I can just type the whole thing myself `"-inc" "-brief"` if necessary.

```
(defun latex-word-count ()
 (interactive)
  (let* ((this-file (buffer-file-name))
     (word-count
      (with-output-to-string
        (with-current-buffer standard-output
          (call-process "texcount" nil t nil "-inc" "-brief" this-file)))))
(string-match "\n$" word-count)
(message (replace-match "" nil nil word-count))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
 
   (defun latex-word-count ()
      (interactive)
      (let* ((this-file  (buffer-file-name))
             (options    (let ((opts  ())
                               opt)
                           (while (not (equal (setq opt  (read-string "Option: "))
                                              ""))
                             (push opt opts))
                           (nreverse opts)))
             (word-count (with-output-to-string
                             (with-current-buffer standard-output
                               (apply 'call-process "texcount" nil t nil
                                      (append options (list this-file)))))))
        (string-match "\n$" word-count)
        (message (replace-match "" nil nil word-count))))
```

That lets you input as many options as you like, in the order you want.  End by hitting <kbd>RET</kbd> with no typed input.

If you know what options are acceptable to `texcount`, then you can use `completing-read` instead of `read-string`, providing a list of those options as its `COLLECTION` argument. HTH.